# "Beautifying" a ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

The following code to draw a ContourPlot creates a thick line (in some places only) along the diagonal. Since in some places the line is thinner, I wonder if there is anything I can do to reduce the thickness throughout?

```
ContourPlot[((256 ((1 - p1) p1)^(7/
          2) Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)])/(4 (1 - p1) p1 - 
        4 (1 - p2) p2)^2 - (512 (1 - p1) p1 ((1 - p2) p2)^(5/2))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 + 
        4 (1 - p2) p2)^2 + (256 ((1 - p1) p1)^(5/2) (1 - p2) p2 (-2 + 
         Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)]))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 - 4 (1 - p2) p2)^2 + 
    16 (1 - p1)^2 p1^2 (3 Sqrt[
         1/((1 - p2) p2)] - (32 ((1 - p2) p2)^(3/2))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 + 
           4 (1 - p2) p2)^2) - (16 ((1 - p1) p1)^(3/
          2) (4 (1 - p1) p1 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)] + 
         4 (1 - p2) p2 (-3 + 2 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)])))/(4 (1 - 
          p1) p1 - 4 (1 - p2) p2) + (2 (-384 (1 - p1)^3 p1^3 + 
         768 (1 - p1)^2 p1^2 (1 - p2) p2 + 
         128 (1 - p2)^3 p2^3 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)] - 
         128 (1 - p1) p1 (1 - p2)^2 p2^2 (1 + 
            3 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)])))/(Sqrt[
        1/((1 - p1) p1)] Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)] (4 (1 - p1) p1 - 
          4 (1 - p2) p2)^2))/(8 Sqrt[(1 - p2) p2]), {p1, 0.5, 1}, {p2, 0.5, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(2\)]\)"}]
```

[image]

Comment: The 'line' in the plot is caused by the function having the value of `1/0` when `p1 == p2`. Why would you want to hide that?

Comment: I don't want to hide this fact. But the way the ContourPlot shows this fact is crude in my view. Its not homogeneous along the 45 degrees. Like I said, the line is thick some places and thin at others.

Comment: Try removing the `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` options.

Comment: That makes things much worse.

Comment: `PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 0` gives a fairly consistent thickness for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `fun` be the OP's function.  If you simplify the expression, the removable discontinuity along `p1 == p2` cancels out.  Here's one way to help with the algebra: rewrite the function in terms of `u1^2 == p1(1 - p1)` and `u2^2 == p2(1 - p2)`.  Then the function becomes a rational function, which is much easier to simplify.  Back substitution brings the simplified expression back to an equivalent function of `p1` and `p2`.

```
Simplify[fun /. {
   1 - p1 -> 1 - p1,     (* trick to replace just p1 in p1(1-p1) *)
   p1 -> u1^2/(1 - p1),
   1 - p2 -> 1 - p2,     (* trick to replace just p2 in p2(1-p2) *)
   p2 -> u2^2/(1 - p2)},
 u1 > 0 && u2 > 0]
fun2 = % /. {u1 -> Sqrt[p1 (1 - p1)], u2 -> Sqrt[p2 (1 - p2)]};
(*
  (2 u1 u2 (u1^4 + 2 u1^3 u2 - 2 u1^2 u2^2 + 2 u1 u2^3 + u2^4)) /
    ((u1 + u2)^2 (u1^2 + u2^2))
*)

ContourPlot[fun2, {p1, 0.5, 1}, {p2, 0.5, 1},
 FrameLabel -> {HoldForm@Subscript[p, 1], HoldForm@Subscript[p, 2]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As you've written the function, I agree with @RohitNamjoshi : "Why would you want to hide that?"

But if you're willing (or better yet "able") to use the limit as `p2 -> p1` as the result for when `p1 = p2` and also use the `Exclusions->None` option, then the line disappears.  (Or you could add in a nice uniform line afterwards.)

```
FullSimplify[Limit[((256 ((1 - p1) p1)^(7/2) Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)])/(4 (1 - p1) p1 - 
  4 (1 - p2) p2)^2 - (512 (1 - p1) p1 ((1 - p2) p2)^(5/2))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 + 
  4 (1 - p2) p2)^2 + (256 ((1 - p1) p1)^(5/2) (1 - p2) p2 (-2 +
  Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)]))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 - 4 (1 - p2) p2)^2 + 
  16 (1 - p1)^2 p1^2 (3 Sqrt[1/((1 - p2) p2)] - (32 ((1 - p2) p2)^(3/2))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 + 
  4 (1 - p2) p2)^2) - (16 ((1 - p1) p1)^(3/2) (4 (1 - p1) p1 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)] + 
  4 (1 - p2) p2 (-3 + 2 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)])))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 - 
  4 (1 - p2) p2) + (2 (-384 (1 - p1)^3 p1^3 + 768 (1 - p1)^2 p1^2 (1 - p2) p2 + 
  128 (1 - p2)^3 p2^3 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)] - 128 (1 - p1) p1 (1 - p2)^2 p2^2 (1 + 3 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)])))/(Sqrt[
  1/((1 - p1) p1)] Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)] (4 (1 - 
  p1) p1 - 4 (1 - p2) p2)^2))/(8 Sqrt[(1 - p2) p2]), p2 -> p1], Assumptions -> 0 < p1 < 1]

(* -(-1 + p1) p1 *)
```

So we write the function as

```
f[p1_, p2_] := If[p1 == p2, p1 (1 - p1), 
  ((256 ((1 - p1) p1)^(7/2) Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)])/(4 (1 - p1) p1 - 
  4 (1 - p2) p2)^2 - (512 (1 - p1) p1 ((1 - p2) p2)^(5/2))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 + 
  4 (1 - p2) p2)^2 + (256 ((1 - p1) p1)^(5/2) (1 - p2) p2 (-2 +
  Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)]))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 - 4 (1 - p2) p2)^2 + 
  16 (1 - p1)^2 p1^2 (3 Sqrt[1/((1 - p2) p2)] - (32 ((1 - p2) p2)^(3/
  2))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 + 4 (1 - p2) p2)^2) - (16 ((1 - p1) p1)^(3/
  2) (4 (1 - p1) p1 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)] + 4 (1 - p2) p2 (-3 + 
  2 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)])))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 - 
  4 (1 - p2) p2) + (2 (-384 (1 - p1)^3 p1^3 + 768 (1 - p1)^2 p1^2 (1 - p2) p2 + 
  128 (1 - p2)^3 p2^3 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)] - 
  128 (1 - p1) p1 (1 - p2)^2 p2^2 (1 + 3 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)])))/(Sqrt[
  1/((1 - p1) p1)] Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)] (4 (1 - 
  p1) p1 - 4 (1 - p2) p2)^2))/(8 Sqrt[(1 - p2) p2])]
```

With the contour plot given by the following:

```
ContourPlot[f[p1, p2], {p1, 0.5, 1}, {p2, 0.5, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(2\)]\)"},
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Contour plot]

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr[p1_, p2_] = ((256 ((1 - p1) p1)^(7/
           2) Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)])/(4 (1 - p1) p1 - 
         4 (1 - p2) p2)^2 - (512 (1 - 
          p1) p1 ((1 - p2) p2)^(5/2))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 + 
         4 (1 - p2) p2)^2 + (256 ((1 - p1) p1)^(5/2) (1 - p2) p2 (-2 + 
          Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)]))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 - 
         4 (1 - p2) p2)^2 + 
     16 (1 - p1)^2 p1^2 (3 Sqrt[
          1/((1 - p2) p2)] - (32 ((1 - p2) p2)^(3/2))/(4 (1 - p1) p1 + 
            4 (1 - p2) p2)^2) - (16 ((1 - p1) p1)^(3/
           2) (4 (1 - p1) p1 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)] + 
          4 (1 - p2) p2 (-3 + 2 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)])))/(4 (1 - 
           p1) p1 - 
        4 (1 - p2) p2) + (2 (-384 (1 - p1)^3 p1^3 + 
          768 (1 - p1)^2 p1^2 (1 - p2) p2 + 
          128 (1 - p2)^3 p2^3 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)] - 
          128 (1 - p1) p1 (1 - p2)^2 p2^2 (1 + 
             3 Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)])))/(Sqrt[
         1/((1 - p1) p1)] Sqrt[((1 - p2) p2)/((1 - p1) p1)] (4 (1 - p1) p1 - 
           4 (1 - p2) p2)^2))/(8 Sqrt[(1 - p2) p2]);
```

The function domain is

```
fd = FunctionDomain[expr[p1, p2], {p1, p2}]

(* 0 < p1 < 1 && 0 < p2 < 1 && p1 - p2 != 0 && 
 p1 + p2 != 1 && -p1 + p1^2 - p2 + p2^2 != 0 *)
```

Start by simplifying the expression

```
expr2[p1_, p2_] = expr[p1, p2] // Simplify[#, fd] &;

LeafCount /@ {expr[p1, p2], expr2[p1, p2]}

(* {489, 357} *)
```

For the case `p2 == p1`

```
Limit[expr2[p1, p2], p2 -> p1]

(* -(-1 + p1) p1 *)

expr2[p_, p_] = p (1 - p);

ContourPlot[
  expr2[p1, p2], {p1, 1/2, 1}, {p2, 1/2, 1},
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  MaxRecursion -> 2,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(2\)]\)"}] //
 Quiet
```

[image]